# HAML - "expecting end-of-input" Ruby error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

can anyone see why i'd be getting this error in my code?

if i remove the error trapping it works fine but can't see what the issue is with the error trapping.

thanks

```
 = simple_form_for @pic, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
      - if @pic.errors.any?
        #errors
          %h2 
          = pluralize(@pic.errors.count, "error")
            prevented this Pic from saving
            %ul
              - @pic.errors.full_message.each do |msg|
                %li= msg

      .form-group
        = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
      .form-group
        = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form_control' }

      = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-info"
```

Comment: Double check indentation and and spacing.

Comment: Can you check you indentation and make sure it's consistent? For more info [check this](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/#indentation). Also make sure your indentation is consistent with application.html.haml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has indentation problem, try this

```
= simple_form_for @pic, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  - if @pic.errors.any?
    #errors
      %h2 
        = pluralize(@pic.errors.count, "error")
        prevented this Pic from saving
        %ul
          - @pic.errors.full_message.each do |msg|
            %li= msg

  .form-group
    = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
  .form-group
    = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form_control' }

  = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-info"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: cheers buddy :) worked a treat. i thought i had the indents sorted :) clearly missed one or 2 :D thanks alot